# Where do the xhr parameters reside?

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest, google-chrome-devtools, text-extraction, firefox-developer-tools

This sound like pretty silly question (even to me) but since this is all very far from my area of competence (if any...), I have to ask those who know more:

I was trying to help someone to scrape data [from this web page](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/peak-design/travel-tripod-by-peak-design?ref=discovery_category_newest). Using the Developer tab, I quickly found out that the page makes a `get()` request to

```
https://api-cdn.embed.ly/1/card-details
```

Usually, the target data is in the response, but it this case it was in the parameters themselves:

```
params = (
    ('card', '1'),
    ('key', 'fd92ebbc52fc43fb98f69e50e7893c13'),
    ('native', 'true'),
    ('scheme', 'https'),
    ('urls', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8f82p6Do9cc,https://youtu.be/ILUHWQqlGy0,https://youtu.be/lZPlvh55P1g,https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aDSmK_gLwE,https://youtu.be/vAnF-Hvlc0w,https://youtu.be/ZUI4m8cDFMQ,https://youtu.be/ILUHWQqlGy0'),
    ('v', 'MTcyMDEw'),
    ('youtube_showinfo', '0'),
)
```

So, it turns out, I don't need to capture the response, but I do need to (programmatically, not by copying from the developer tab) capture the request. What I can't figure out is where in the page (or anywhere else) are the request parameters located? For example, as can be seen above, one of the target parameters (`urls`) consists of a bunch of urls; these urls aren't in the page itself (that I can find). So, to generate the request, these must be read from somewhere - where is that somewhere located?

Again, sorry for the newbie-type question, but there must be something fundamental I'm missing.

Comment: Open the page in a browser, go to developer tools and inspect source tab by searching key value or url v params value in all files.

Comment: @omegastripes - I obviously did that; this is how I got the parameters in the question. What I need to know is where do the developer tools find these parameters?

Comment: In files like scripts linked to HTML document.

Comment: it would help to know what you were trying to scrape from that page.

Comment: @Qharr - For this purpose, let's say I'm after the urls, for example. Again, just to emphasize, I'm not trying to scrape the urls from a copy and paste output of the developer tools (that's easy enough); I'm trying to find out where the tools locate this info to begin with and extract it programatically.